# Spring Boot error: AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, orm

I am new to Spring Boot. I tried to do an Authentication module where user can `Register` and `Login` Based in their role. I have written the logic for user registration and then when I run this it's not running but show me:

> Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for collection: net.osmanforhad.main.model.User.roles column: user_id

here is the many to many relation code:

```
@Column(name = "roles")
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(
        name = "users_roles",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"
                )
        )
private Collection<Role> roles;
```

is there any one to suggest me how i should fix this issue
.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I think i made mistake in my model file here is the actual error i have find: **Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for collection: net.osmanforhad.main.model.User.roles column: user_id**

Comment: Can you show me your `User` as well as `Roles` entity?

Comment: here is the correction : @JoinTable(
        name = "users_roles",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"
                )
        )
private Collection<Role> roles; i wrote user_id twice insted of role id that's why i got repeated column in the mapping error.. Thanks for your support .. Thank you again